# Migrating TensorFlow serving 1 to 2, RESSOURCE_EXHAUSTED from grpc calls

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

We are trying to migrate from /tensorflow/serving:1.12 to /tensorflow/serving:2.8.2, we use grpc calls to get the recommendation, we have two types of calls, one for each memeber where the grpc call ask for recommendation for one member, and another type where we sent batches of memebers, with TF1 everything worked fine, now with TF2, for the first type it workes fine, for the batch calls we get an error on the grpc side:

```
[2022-10-19 16:22:01.454] [      Thread-53] [batch-slave:e4ccd2a7-e0d7-4cc0-9481-b3d98fec3df8] ERROR AgoraRecSysBatchService - Failed while processing : e4ccd2a7-e0d7-4cc0-9481-b3d98fec3df8
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:534)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:562)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:743)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:722)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here our base image

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.8.2

COPY entry.py /usr/bin/entry.py
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apt update && \
  apt install -y python3 python3-pip wget && \
  mkdir /bucket && \
  chmod +x /usr/bin/entry.py && \
  apt autoremove -y && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

RUN wget -P /bin https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe/releases/download/v0.2.0/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64 && \
    mv /bin/grpc_health_probe-linux-amd64 /bin/grpc_health_probe && \
      chmod +x /bin/grpc_health_probe

# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entry.py"]
```

in Production we have a configured batched size of 100 memebers for each request, and we can have up to 30K memeber in one call.

Client ask for recomendation of 30K members in http -> we get the request in one pod and create mini batch grpc request to tf serving until we get all of them then we respond with an http response of the hole 30k.

Do you have any idea what could be the issue, specially from the exhausted ressources, there is no info that can help as a lead, because we have sufficient pods, and sufficient ressouces, we are using GKE and there is no spike in the pods.

Edit:

Code we use to train with tf2:

```
 def train_step(self, batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        scores = self(batch, training=True)['similarity']
        scores = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(scores)
        pos_scores, neg_scores = self.split_pos_neg(scores)
        labels = self.get_classification_labels()
        loss = self.compiled_loss(labels, scores)
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

    self.histogram(pos_scores, neg_scores)
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(labels, scores)

    results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    results['pos_neg_score'] = pos_better_neg(pos_scores, neg_scores)

    return results
```

Comment: The issue happens in Prod and on other all environment, where we have multiple pods and enough memory, i managed to reproduce locally just to see at which point we get the error, or is it related to memory, but as i said locally it worked for like 30 memmbers in batch more than we started getting the RESSOURCE EXHAUSTED error.
In prod when we test with around 3K i think, we get that error, but i ll check ur answer and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

TF1 in eager mode and TF2 in graph mode, bandwidths elapse when using TF2 with TF1 remote execution but you can use GradientTape.

When changes are not determined by themselves but accumulate, myself held all my values into vanes.

TF1 session required placeholder or tf.Variable.

```
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=( (1, 28, 28)))
y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1,))

loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square((X - y)))
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
        train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X:list_image, y:list_label})
```

GradientTape watch variables and calculate accumulate values.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        result = self.model( inputs=tf.constant( content_batch[0], shape=( 1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL ) ) )
        result = tf.constant( result, shape=( 2, 1 ) )
        predict_label = tf.Variable( tf.constant( self.model.trainable_weights[len(self.model.trainable_weights) - 1], shape=( 2, 1 ) ) )
        loss_value =  self.loss( result.numpy(), current_label )
        loss_value =  tf.Variable( tf.constant( loss_value, shape=( 1, ) ).numpy() )
        tape.watch( loss_value )
gradients = tape.gradient( loss_value, loss_value )
self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_weights))
```

Comment: Hi Jirayu, sorry for the late answer, i checked the code that we use for training they already use GradientTape, i edited my post with the code we use to train

Comment: Hi, that is because communication it cannot update back worker can I have more specific logs or communication messages? It is same you running on different versions but you dont have correct tricker message in SQL profile different versions but this is protocols issues.

Comment: we just solved the issue lately, after along time, by the way we use GradientTape already, and the issue didn't come from the model that was already trained, it is betwwen grpc and tf2, as in tf2 they did some changes that affected the communication between both those two, there an option that exist in tf2 serving that raise more threads so we did that and after some tests it is working correctly, thanks for the help anyway ;)